# $a_{n+2}=\frac{2}{a_{n+1}}+a_{n}.$ and $a_{1}=1,a_{2}=2$.Then value of $a_{2017}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If ${a_{n}}$ be a sequence defined by $\displaystyle a_{n+2}=\frac{2}{a_{n+1}}+a_{n}.$ and $a_{1}=1,a_{2}=2$.Then value of $a_{2017}$

Try: $$a_{n+2}a_{n+1}-a_{n}a_{n+1}=2\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n-1}}$$

$$\sum^{2015}_{n=1}\left(a_{n+2}a_{n+1}-a_{n}a_{n+1}\right)=2\sum^{2015}_{n=1}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n-1}}\right)$$

$$a_{2017}a_{2016}-a_{2}a_{3}=a_{2015}a_{2016}$$

Could some help me to solve it, Thanks

Comment: ...A question from last year.

Comment: How do we define $a_3$?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Could you provide a link?

Comment: @S.C.B. I deduced from the subscript. Generally contest based question use the year number in questions.

Comment: @lhf, I think the typo is more likely in $\dfrac{2}{a_{n\color{red}{+}1}}$

Comment: You shouldn't just disappear after posting the question, at least be there for 5-10mins, or revisit in short time intervals.

Comment: if answer is 1/2 , then there is a typo as @Prasun Biswas stated.

Comment: Sorry friends i have edited my question.

Comment: @Durgesh Tiwari , what's the answer?

Comment: Actually i dont have answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** apply a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) to
$$
a_{n+2}a_{n+1}-a_{n+1}a_n=2
$$

---

The solution of the equation above is $a_{n+1}a_n=2n$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{2n+2}}{a_{2n}}
&=1+\frac{2}{a_{2n+1}a_{2n}}\\
&=1+\frac1{2n}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n+2}
&=2\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2n+1}{2n}\\
&=\frac{4n+2}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align}
$$
Since $a_{2n+2}a_{2n+1}=4n+2$, we get
$$
a_{2n+1}=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}
$$
Thus,
$$
a_{2017}=\frac{4^{1008}}{\binom{2016}{1008}}
$$

Comment: Robjohn please tell how can i found $a_{2016}$ in $a_{2017}a_{2016}-2=2015\times 2=4030.$

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari, Are you sure that the problem asks for the exact value of $a_{2017}$ ? There doesn't seem to be a "nice" exact form for $a_{2017}$. The best results you can get is that $a_{n+1}a_n=2n~\forall~n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n-1}}=\dfrac{n}{n-1}~\forall~n\gt 1$. Numerical computation for $a_{2017}$ yields the [following result](http://mathb.in/21941) (which I'm linking here since it is too lengthy to be written in this comment).

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari there doesn't seem to be a nice exact solution. I too came up with that telescopic series and got stuck at the value of $a_{2016}$. robjohn answer is also not something which you can directly compute on paper