# A sequence satisfies $a_{n+2} = \frac{2}{a_{n+1}} + a_n$ where $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2$. Find the value of $\frac{2^{2009}}{2011}a_{2012}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm a grade 12 math student, and this was one of the questions in one of the hardest modules.
Recurrence relations are not actually in our syllabus, so I expect that the solution probably involves a neat way of eliminating terms, maybe even a telescoping series type of approach.

I tried writing the equation as $ a_{n+2} - a_{n} = \frac{2}{a_{n+1}} $
and sought a relation between the terms.
At first it felt like it was working, as $a_5  - a_3 = 3 - \frac{1}{3}$ and $a_6 - a_4  = 4 - \frac{1}{4}$
but then $a_7 - a_5  = 5 + \frac{1}{5}$ and after that the numbers cannot be expressed in this form

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2616163/42969

Comment: Yes it does, I believe that these posts didn't show up, when I was trying to search for this question.

Comment: Found with Approach0: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a_%7Bn%2B2%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%20%2B%20a_n%24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Multiply the recurrence relation by $a_{n+1}$ to get $$a_{n+2}a_{n+1} = a_{n+1}a_n+2.$$ Then, since $a_2a_1 = 2$, you can use induction to show that $a_{n+1}a_n = 2n$ for all $n$. Now, try to use the equations $a_3a_2 = 4$, $a_4a_3 = 6$, $a_5a_4 = 8$, ... along with the given $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$ to find a formula for $a_n$.